# capture first n characters of every line

Tags: regex, grep

I'm having troubles capturing the  first 6 characters of every line. Supposing I have the following lines inside text.txt:

```
this is a sentence
1234567890
string
```

I would like to get the first 10 chars:

```
this i
123456
string
```

I've tried running `grep -Eo "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*{6}" text.txt`

But grep recycles the regex at every 6th position instead of starting at the next new line. it ends up returning:

```
this i
s a se
ntence
123456
7890..
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What does the `*` do there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why to use `grep`, you can use simple `cut` command:

```
cut -c1-6 file
```

OR else this more complex sed will also work:

```
sed 's/^\(.\{6\}\).*$/\1/' file
```

Comment: Made me laugh.. why use `grep` when `cut` is simpler or how about some more complex than a simple `grep` :)

Comment: @sudo_O: I believe no other command can beat simplicity of `cut`. btw `grep -Eo "^.{6}"` didn't even work for me on OSX.

Comment: I managed to match it not beat it http://stackoverflow.com/a/19142970/1066031 Hmmm I logged into a Mac at it seems it doesn't anchor with `^` *(`man` says it should)*.. strange!?

Answer (score 1):

Use following command:

```
grep -Eo "^.{6}" text.txt
```

Above command omit lines with <6 characters. To include such lines, use following command:

```
grep -Eo "^.{1,6}" text.txt
```

Comment: what version of grep are you using ? This doesn't work 2.5.1 GNU grep on RHEL-6.

Comment: @iamauser, I'm using GNU grep *2.14*.

Comment: `echo 'this is a sentence' | grep -Eo "^.{6}"` will print 3 lines actually: `this i`,
`s a se`,
`ntence`

Comment: @anubhava, `echo 'this is a sentence' | grep -Eo "^.{6}"` prints only `this i` in  my system.

Comment: Hmm may be due to the fact I am on OSX

Comment: @anubhava - Try to use `-Po` switch instead of `-Eo`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `grep`, then try

```
grep -Po "^.{6}" text.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for regular expressions:

```
$ pr -mtw6 file
this i
123456
string
```